# Change various strings to timestamp Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time

Given all possible time formats I can get from my user (chatbot):

```
09:03
9:23A.M.
9:23 A.m.
13:44 pm
20:00 P.m
15:40
00:00
12:33
4:33p.M
...
```

I want to convert them to appropriate time. There won't be one format I can use.

Please advise how to solve such issue?

I have tried with `strptime` from the `datetime` package but I need to specify format and it can be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

Find my answer thanks to this [amazing](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) source!
Posting for others:

```
dateutil
```

The dateutil module is an extension to the datetime module. We don't need to pass any parsing code to parse a string. For example:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

datetime = parse('2018-06-29 22:21:41')

print(datetime)
This parse function will parse the string automatically and store it in the datetime variable. Parsing is done automatically. You don't have to mention any format string. Let's try to parse different types of strings using dateutil:

from dateutil.parser import parse

date_array = [
    '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860',
    'Jun 28 2018  7:40AM',
    'Jun 28 2018 at 7:40AM',
    'September 18, 2017, 22:19:55',
    'Sun, 05/12/1999, 12:30PM',
    'Mon, 21 March, 2015',
    '2018-03-12T10:12:45Z',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00',
    'Tuesday , 6th September, 2017 at 4:30pm'
]

for date in date_array:
    print('Parsing: ' + date)
    dt = parse(date)
    print(dt.date())
    print(dt.time())
    print(dt.tzinfo)
    print('\n')

Output:

$ python3 dateutil-1.py
Parsing: 2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860
2018-06-29
08:15:27.243860
None

Parsing: Jun 28 2018  7:40AM
2018-06-28
07:40:00
None

Parsing: Jun 28 2018 at 7:40AM
2018-06-28
07:40:00
None

Parsing: September 18, 2017, 22:19:55
2017-09-18
22:19:55
None

Parsing: Sun, 05/12/1999, 12:30PM
1999-05-12
12:30:00
None

Parsing: Mon, 21 March, 2015
2015-03-21
00:00:00
None

Parsing: 2018-03-12T10:12:45Z
2018-03-12
10:12:45
tzutc()

Parsing: 2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00
2018-06-29
17:08:00.586525
tzutc()

Parsing: 2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00
2018-06-29
17:08:00.586525
tzoffset(None, 18000)

Parsing: Tuesday , 6th September, 2017 at 4:30pm
2017-09-06
16:30:00
None
```

You can see that almost any type of string can be parsed easily using the dateutil module.

```
Maya
```

Maya also makes it very easy to parse a string and for changing timezones. Some simple examples are shown below:

```
import maya

dt = maya.parse('2018-04-29T17:45:25Z').datetime()
print(dt.date())
print(dt.time())
print(dt.tzinfo)
Output:

$ python3 maya-1.py
2018-04-29
17:45:25
UTC
For converting the time to a different timezone:

import maya

dt = maya.parse('2018-04-29T17:45:25Z').datetime(to_timezone='America/New_York', naive=False)
print(dt.date())
print(dt.time())
print(dt.tzinfo)
Output:

$ python3 maya-2.py
2018-04-29
13:45:25
America/New_York
```

Now isn't that easy to use? Let's try out `maya` with the same set of strings we have used with `dateutil`:

```
import maya

date_array = [
    '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860',
    'Jun 28 2018  7:40AM',
    'Jun 28 2018 at 7:40AM',
    'September 18, 2017, 22:19:55',
    'Sun, 05/12/1999, 12:30PM',
    'Mon, 21 March, 2015',
    '2018-03-12T10:12:45Z',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00',
    'Tuesday , 6th September, 2017 at 4:30pm'
]

for date in date_array:
    print('Parsing: ' + date)
    dt = maya.parse(date).datetime()
    print(dt)
    print(dt.date())
    print(dt.time())
    print(dt.tzinfo)
Output:

$ python3 maya-3.py
Parsing: 2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860
2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860+00:00
2018-06-29
08:15:27.243860
UTC

Parsing: Jun 28 2018  7:40AM
2018-06-28 07:40:00+00:00
2018-06-28
07:40:00
UTC

Parsing: Jun 28 2018 at 7:40AM
2018-06-28 07:40:00+00:00
2018-06-28
07:40:00
UTC

Parsing: September 18, 2017, 22:19:55
2017-09-18 22:19:55+00:00
2017-09-18
22:19:55
UTC

Parsing: Sun, 05/12/1999, 12:30PM
1999-05-12 12:30:00+00:00
1999-05-12
12:30:00
UTC

Parsing: Mon, 21 March, 2015
2015-03-21 00:00:00+00:00
2015-03-21
00:00:00
UTC

Parsing: 2018-03-12T10:12:45Z
2018-03-12 10:12:45+00:00
2018-03-12
10:12:45
UTC

Parsing: 2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00
2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00
2018-06-29
17:08:00.586525
UTC

Parsing: 2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00
2018-06-29 12:08:00.586525+00:00
2018-06-29
12:08:00.586525
UTC

Parsing: Tuesday , 6th September, 2017 at 4:30pm
2017-09-06 16:30:00+00:00
2017-09-06
16:30:00
UTC
```

As you can see, all date formats were parsed, but did you notice the difference? If we are not providing the timezone info it automatically converts it to UTC. So, it is important to note that we need to provide to_timezone and naive parameters if the time is not in UTC.